# Is the following sequence a null sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've been asked if the following sequence is a null sequence. $$\frac{(-1)^n}{10}.$$
I know the def of a null sequence is, a sequence $\lbrace a_{n}\rbrace$ is null if for each positive number $\varepsilon$ there is a value $X$ such that $|a_{n}|<\varepsilon$ for all values of $n > X$.

I'm just unsure of how to know if this is a null sequence or not. And if not, then how to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify the given term as follows: $$\frac{(-1)^n}{10}=-\frac{1}{10}$$ if $n$ is odd and in the other case if $n$ is even we get $$\frac{(-1)^n}{10}=\frac{1}{10}$$

Comment: So would I be right in saying then that this sequence is not a null sequence as if I chose ε=1/20 then no matter what value of X I chose it would always lie outside of the strip {-1/20,1/20}

Comment: yes this sequence is not a null sequence